How do i save the pulled data into a proper format in excel?
so i am trying to pull data from MISP and then save it into a csv file format.
I tried by pulling just one event but already got this error
an image of what i got when i try to open the csv file
A short example of the result inside the csv file. These codes were all stored in one row/one column
An example of the data inside the csv
{'id': '1', 'orgc_id': '2', 'org_id': '1', 'date': '2014-10-02', 'threat_level_id': '3', 'info': 'OSINT ShellShock scanning IPs from OpenDNS', 'published': True, 'uuid': '542e4c9c-cadc-4f8f-bb11-6d13950d210b', 'attribute_count': '1067', 'analysis': '2', 'timestamp': '1517817037', 'distribution': '3', 'proposal_email_lock': False, 'locked': False, 'publish_timestamp': '1610092628', 'sharing_group_id': '0', 'disable_correlation': False, 'extends_uuid': '', 'protected': None, 'Org': {'id': '1', 'name': 'OTISAC', 'uuid': '02ba0e53-d88e-420f-bd3a-f9150149f4e7', 'local': True}, 'Orgc': {'id': '2', 'name': 'CthulhuSPRL.be', 'uuid': '55f6ea5f-fd34-43b8-ac1d-40cb950d210f', 'local': False}, 'Attribute': [{'id': '1', 'type': 'link', 'category': 'External analysis', 'to_ids': False, 'uuid': '542e4cbd-ee78-4a57-bfb8-1fda950d210b', 'event_id': '1', 'distribution': '5', 'timestamp': '1412320445', 'comment': '', 'sharing_group_id': '0', 'deleted': False, 'disable_correlation': False, 'object_id': '0', 'object_relation': None, 'first_seen': None, 'last_seen': None, 'value':
so my question now is, how can i rewrite the code to save the data properly?
Below is my current code:
# The URL of the MISP instance to connect to
misp_url = 'https://misp.otisac.org/'

# Your MISP authentication key
misp_key = 'qCrtLX4ubnNAnpvFbgHwDf5KhsnDvfIS5HVRvSaM'

# Verify the MISP server's certificate
misp_verifycert = True

from pymisp import PyMISP
import csv

try:
    misp = PyMISP(misp_url, misp_key, misp_verifycert)

    # Fetch event with ID 1 (modify as needed)
    r = misp.search(eventid=[1], metadata=False, pythonify=False)

    print("Response:", r)  # Debugging statement to understand the structure of the response

    # Extract relevant data from the JSON response
    event_data = []  # List to store extracted data
    for event in r:
        event_values = []  # List to store values for each event
        for key, value in event.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                # Handle list values (e.g., tags)
                value = ','.join(value)
            event_values.append(value)  # Append extracted data
        event_data.append(event_values)  # Append values for each event to the main list

    # Create CSV header row based on extracted keys
    csv_headers = list(r[0].keys())

    # Open CSV file for writing
    with open('C:\\misp_event_data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(csv_headers)  # Write header row
        
        # Write each event's data as separate rows
        writer.writerows(event_data)  # Write the extracted event data

    print("Event data saved to misp_event_data.csv")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")



CSV format should be one line per record, n values per record, with each record in the form v1,v2,...,vn.  Yours looks like it's confused between JavaScript and CSV.  Fix your CSV.

@churchill291 omg... your suggestion works!! Thank you so much, i was panicking so much over the error and had no idea how to fix it.. Thank you!!!

It looks like you're formatting the json formatted return from the misp.search() into a csv format to export. You can actually save yourself some headache and set the property in your misp search call 'return_format' to equal 'csv'. This will return instead a comma delineated string ready for export instead of the json format you're working within. By default it produces a json.  This will help you on your formatting issue and save you some time!
This would look like:
# Fetch event with ID 1 (modify as needed)
r = misp.search(eventid=[1], metadata=False, pythonify=False, return_format='csv')

Hope this helps!
